# permutation algorithm in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, permutation

I was trying to permutate using java and i noticed my code works for strings but the same algorithm does not work correctly on Arrays

here's the code for strings

```
public static void Recurse(String s,int i)
{
    for(int j=i;j<(s.length());j++)
    {   
        s=Swap(s,i,j);
     if(i<(s.length()-1))
     {  
        Recurse(s,i+1); 
     }
        if(i==(s.length()-1))
        {   
            Display(s);        
        }
    }       
}   
   public static String Swap(String newString,int i,int j)
{
    char  newChar[]=newString.toCharArray();
    char temp=newChar[i];
    newChar[i]=newChar[j];
    newChar[j]=temp;

    return String.valueOf(newChar);
}

    public static void Display(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String i=new String("123");
    Recurse(i,0);
 }
```

output:
123
132
213
231
312
321
works fine.

then here is the code for arrays

```
public static void Recurse(int [] newArray,int i)
{ 
    for(int j=i;j<newArray.length;j++)
    {
    Swap(newArray,i,j);
    if(i<(newArray.length-1))
    {
        Recurse(newArray,i+1);
    }   
    if(i==(newArray.length-1))
    {
        Display(newArray);
    }   

    }   

}

public static void Display(int [] Array)
{
    for(int i: Array)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    Recurse(new int[] {1,2,3},0);
}
```

output 
123 
132
312 
321
123
132

Does not work correctly,So i was wondering what went wrong here.

Comment: Could you post the code for the `Swap` method?

Comment: i have reedited the code

Comment: Are you using the same `Swap` method for your `Array` version?

Comment: no,the array was swapped using temp variables,but strings are immutable so i had to convert to charArray then return a new String object to swap the string.

Comment: You should avoid the String -> char[] -> String conversion. Just operate on char[] and to the from/to String conversion and the beginning/end.

Comment: Robert what do you mean by "from/to String conversion and the beginning/end".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output seems to be correct with below code:

```
public static void recurse(int[] newArray, int i) {
    for (int j = i; j < newArray.length; j++) {
        newArray = swap(newArray, i, j);
        if (i < (newArray.length - 1)) {
            recurse(newArray, i + 1);
        }
        if (i == (newArray.length - 1)) {
            display(newArray);
        }
    }
}

private static int[] swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int[] newArray = a.clone();
    int temp = newArray[i];
    newArray[i] = newArray[j];
    newArray[j] = temp;
    return newArray;
}

public static void display(int[] Array) {
    for (int i : Array) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    recurse(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 0);
}
```

the output is : 
123
132
213
231
312
321

I just made few changes in `swap` methods code, I made it similar to the one which you used in `Strings swap` method.

Comment: Thanks ,this works ,but what exactly is the difference between this swap function and the other one that is making them produce different output

Comment: @user9169047 Array is a referenceType, on passing it to the method the actual values in it will be changed. and the logic to permute numbers needs the array to be in its earlier state.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so when `Recurse(String s,int i)` calls `Recurse(s,i+1);`, the value of `s` remains unchanged.

Arrays are mutable, so when `Recurse(int [] newArray,int i)` calls `Recurse(newArray,i+1);`, the value of `newArray` is changed.

That is why they behave differently.

<sup>*Note:* When I say "the value of" I'm referring to the value of the object, not the value of the reference variable itself.</sup>